# Add Titles to the Side Columns in DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, datagridview

I am attempting to a create a excel-style grid in a C#/Visual Studio application that I am developing. I am aware that you can dynamically add the titles to the DGV on the top row, but is it possible to add a title on the side columns, where the arrow and asterisk are on the image below:

[image]

If  this cannot be achieved with a DataGridView is there a similar element in Windows Forms or Wpf?

Any answers or engagement would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF it's DataGridRowHeader, an example of row number you can find in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowheaderstyle(v=vs.110).aspx),

And in WinForms it's HeaderCell property of DataGridViewRow. And again in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.headercell(v=vs.110).aspx) we can see row number sample.

Comment: This is how to add a number? I want to add text. Doesn't HeaderCell affect the top box, where it says "test"?

Comment: @AdamMcquiff no difference, numbers, or text, whatever you want. Did you try use these samples?

Comment: Yeah it worked! :) is it possible to add rows without adding columns?

Comment: No as i know, but you can hide RowHeader and create one column, will look same

Comment: Do you know of any other WinForm elements that I could use to achieve a calendar style grid?

Comment: You can try to play with TableLayoutPanel